# View not update after variable change in controller after firebase key check

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user =>{        
     if(user){
       var userId: any  = user.uid; 
       var ref = firebase.database().ref('/setting/' + userId);
          ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.exists()){
           let getData = "Checking if setting exist";
           let settingProvided = true;
           console.log('Setting provided');
          }else{
            let settingProvided = false;
          }
      });

     }
   })
```

Views code
      
    
      **Note: Please provide your detail in the setting tab before sending your airtime.**

Comment: "Views code Note: Please provide your detail in the setting tab before sending your airtime." - Wha doest this mean?

Comment: Are you aware that the code in `if (snapshot.exists()){...} else {...}` won't do anything except the output to the console? If you expect this code to have any other effect, please state what this might be.

Comment: Just place a piece of your view code so we can figure out what are you trying to do. In other words your reference on value handler won't update anything...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the implementation of the pure JS SDK in Angular falling out of Zone, so the view doesn't update based on the changes. Import `NgZone` from `@angular/core`, pass it into the constructor like so:

```
constructor(private _zone: NgZone) { }
```

Now when you get the result of your auth state, you can wrap the result in `_zone`:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
  this._zone.run(() => {
    // Your code here
  });
});
```